# UI automation testing of WPF controls seems to ignore bindings

Tags: c#, wpf, unit-testing, xaml

I'm currently trying to figure out how to automate UI testing for my WPF application and I have troubles getting it to work.

The XAML of `MyControl` (which extends `UserControl`) contains the following `CheckBox`:

```
<CheckBox Name="IsFooCheckBox"
    IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsFoo, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

The binding points to a custom data context that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` and that contains the following property:

```
private bool _isFoo;

public bool IsFoo
{
   get { return _isFoo; }
   set
   {
      _isFoo = value;
      OnPropertyChanged("IsFoo");
   }
}
```

The binding is working in production (in the debugger is can see that `_isFoo` is updated whenever I toggle the checkbox).

I'd like to have a test now that toggles the checkbox and checks that the data context is updated (or to check logic that is implemented in the code-behind). The WPF UI Automation framework seems to be exactly what I am looking for, so I wrote the following NUnit test:

```
var myContext = ...

var sut = new MyControl
{
   DataContext = myContext
};

var peer = new CheckBoxAutomationPeer(sut.IsFooCheckBox);
var pattern = peer.GetPattern(PatternInterface.Toggle) as IToggleProvider;
pattern.Toggle();

Assert.That(sut.IsProvidingProfileCheckBox.IsChecked.Value); // works
Assert.That(myContext.IsFoo); // fails
```

While the first `Assert` passes, the second one fails. I do not understand why this happens... it seems that the binding in the XAML file is ignored or that the update is not triggered. Does anybody have a suggestion how to fix my test? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me some time to figure this out, but in the end, it is kind of obvious and described in many places all over the internet. I guess everything is easy as soon as you know what to look for...

The problem of coded UI tests is that the bindings are not resolved automatically. The resolving has to be initiated by calling `Window.ShowWindow`.

I extended my test and added the following snippet:

```
Window window = new Window
{
    Content = sut // the control to test
};
window.Show();
```

Adding this call instantaneously fixed the strange test behavior that I described in my post.

The direct follow-up problem is that this call requires an active UI thread. Because of this, it might be tricky to get the test to run on a build server in a continuous integration environment. However, this depends on the environment (esp. the build server) and is a different question.

Answer (score 0):

Issue originates here

```
public bool IsFoo
{
   get { return _IsFoo; }
   set
   {
      _isFoo = value;
      OnPropertyChanged("IsFoo");
   }
}
```

Once you have invoked

```
pattern.Toggle();
```

you implicitly invoke setter of IsFoo which raises PropertyChanged event and in turn forces to refresh UI elements which have binding associated with IsFoo - to cut a long story short, getter is invoked and instead of **_isFoo** it returns **_IsFoo**. You mistook variable. 
Try to avoid calling OnPropertyChanged method with explicit property name. Instead of this use **CallerMemberName** attribute which retrieves property name.

```
     public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
```

Then you only need below invocation.

```
OnPropertyChanged();
```

Comment: I do not understand the part "instead of _isFoo it returns _IsFoo"... I guess that is a typo, but even if it should have been "IsFoo" I don't get it... the value of `_isFoo` is set before `OnPropertyChange` is called. Why should this be a problem? As I said, the control is working in the UI, it is just not working in the test. (And a side note that is unrelated to the question: using [CallerMemberName] is a good idea, but I have to stay compatible to .net 4.0, so I cannot use it...)

Comment: Just realized the typo already exists in the question... sorry, I edited that out now.

Comment: It invoked OnPropertyChanged, then in turn getter was invoked which return unset IsFoo = false and false was sent to CheckBox and since it was Checked but received false, property changed and one more time setter was invoked. Is it still not working?

Comment: No, it is not. I just adapted your suggestion and included `[CallerMemberName]` - just to give it a try... however, the result is the same. Furthermore, I can see in the debugger that the auto-parameter is now set to "IsFoo", not to "_isFoo" as you suggested as the correct parameter. I still think the implementation of my custom context is correct and that the problem is in the test.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. I was populating textbox with following code:

```
        ValuePattern valuePattern = promptBox.GetCurrentPattern(ValuePattern.Pattern) as ValuePattern;
        valuePattern.SetValue(value);
```

And depending on the value in text box, another button state was supposed to change from Disabled to Enabled.

I've noticed that after automation code above executed, clicking on the window by hand triggered binding to evaluate.

So I just added

```
    System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("{TAB}");
```

after SetValue and it started to work just fine.

Comment: Sorry, but this sounds more like a hack than a solution. :) In the meantime, I'm pretty sure that the root cause is the missing `Window.ShowWindow` call. It might be that your solution works as well, because your simulated key press transitively triggers the same method call, but I prefer the most obvious solution.